# how to get a specific class object

Tags: java, c++, class

I am still quite new to class concept. I have a problem here. for example, i have a class called

```
class p{ 
       int id;
       p(id){
               //constructor

       }
}
```

now, i want to make instances of class p. After i have all the instances. i want to build a function **get_p(pid)** to **return the specific class p which id=pid**, how can i write this part?

I have read c++ and java class tutorials, but i cant sort this out. please help me.

Comment: What have you tried? In Java, you could for example store your p instances in a map where the key is id and the value is the corresponding p.

Comment: Iterate over every class (you'd have to store references to them in an array or some other container) and check whether each class has your desired `id`. Alternatively, you could use a dictionary.

Comment: What behaviour do you want if two or more p objects have the same id? And do you mean you want to return a specific *class* or a specific *instance*?

Answer (score 2):

You're going to have to track this manually, e.g. with a `Map`; there's no way to look up "the object with this specific ID."

Answer (score 1):

Some other class will have to hang onto all those instances and put the `<id, p>` into a map that can do a lookup.  I'd recommend a factory pattern of some kind.

Answer (score 0):

Where will those instances be held? My guess is that you need a class "c" that contains all of your "p" instances.
EG: Class Invoice holds a *collection* of class Item on a property called Items, so when filled and needed, your instance of Invoice would ask Items (which is an instance of a Collection class) for your item via the Id

```
myInvoice.get_Item(Id);
```

Answer (score 0):

With template meta-programming  and Typelist's  (also a meta-programming concept)
you could do such stuff in c++.
But i thing the is has to be a static member or a template parameter.